# Почему не вызывается функция?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Площадь треуголника по 3 сторонам</title>
<script language="javaScript">
function click(){
    alert('123');
    var one = document.getElementById('one').value;
    var two = document.getElementById('two').value;
    var three = document.getElementById('three').value;
    one = one+two+tree;
    var mydiv = document.getElementById('s');
    mydiv.innerHTML = one+'qweqwe';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
1 сторона:<input type="text" id="one"><br>
2 сторона:<input type="text" id="two"><br>
3 сторона:<input type="text" id="three"><br>
<input type="button" value="Считать" onclick="click()"><br>
Площадь равна: <div id="s"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

И у меня один вопрос: почему не вызывается эта функция click()? Я ничего не могу понять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Плохое имя функции: переименуйте click во что-нибудь нормальное и тогда заработает.

Answer (score 1):

Функция совпадает с именем события.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javaScript">
```

это грубо говоря не верно, используйте

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // тип поменяйте
function click(){
    alert('123');
    var one = parseInt(document.getElementById('one').value); // парсить надо значения
    var two = parseInt(document.getElementById('two').value);
    var three = parseInt(document.getElementById('three').value);
    one = one+two+tree;
    var mydiv = document.getElementById('s');
    mydiv.innerHTML = one+'qweqwe';
}
</script>
```